# Python try and except running

Tags: python-3.x

Have the below code to allow for the following commands to work and they both work, however when passing an argument that exists in ACTIONS, it calls the function but still runs the exception too.

```
miner.py  192.168.88.250 stats temp 1000 2000 
miner.py  192.168.88.250 summary
```

---

```
# Get FAN temnperature
def temp():
        WARN = int(sys.argv[4]) # WARN temp is argument 3 from command line 
        CRIT = int(sys.argv[5]) # CRIT temp is argument 4 from command line 
        temp = connect(sys.argv[2])
        fantemp1 = temp['STATS'][1]['fan1']
        fantemp2 = temp['STATS'][1]['fan2']
        fantemp3 = temp['STATS'][1]['fan3']
        print()
        if fantemp1 >= WARN and fantemp1 <= CRIT:
                status = "Fan1, is overheating"
                exitstatus = 1
        elif fantemp2 >= WARN and fantemp2 <= CRIT:
                status = "Fan2, is overheating"
                exitstatus = 1
        elif fantemp3 >= WARN and fantemp3 <= CRIT:
                status = "Fan3, is overheating"
                exitstatus = 1
        elif fantemp1 <= WARN and fantemp1 <= CRIT:
                status = "Fan1, is critical"
                exitstatus = 2
        elif fantemp2 <= WARN and fantemp2 <= CRIT:
                status = "Fan2, is critical"
                exitstatus = 2
        elif fantemp3 <= WARN and fantemp3 <= CRIT:
                status = "Fan3, is critical"
                exitstatus = 2
        else:
                status = "All is okay"
                exitstatus = 0

        #print(status)
        exit(exitstatus)


# For all commends
def all():
        all = connect(sys.argv[2])
        print(all)



try:
   cmd = sys.argv[5]
   actions = ['temp', 'stats', 'chips']
   # check if it's allowed
   if cmd in actions:
      # lookup the function by name in the globals() dictionary
      func = globals()[cmd]
      # call the function
      func()
except:
   all()
```

This seems to work fine, but would still be interested as to why try and except doesn't work.

```
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    cmd = sys.argv[3]
    actions = ['temp', 'stats', 'chips']
    func = globals()[cmd]
      # call the function
    sys.exit(func())
   # check if it's allowed

else:
  all()
```